# Index out of range, when opening folders in Shared Documents

Tags: document-library

Please see the latest edit at the bottom.

I have multiple sites, within the same Sharepoint site, that each have documents within the Shared Documents section of the site. The majority of these sites work perfectly fine, people can view, download, edit, etc, all the files stored there.

There is one site, however, that does not give access to anything the majority of the time. When I try to go into the folders I am greeted with the error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection

This particular site is not setup any differently to the rest and, strangely, it doesn't happen *ALL* the time, just the majority of the time.

Why would this be happening? What should I do to stop it?

EDIT: I can open the folders in Windows Explorer and see everything I need to see, it's just when trying to view them inside the Shared Documents library that the error occurs.

I have tried removing and re-adding all the documents to see if it made any difference, but it didn't. Still index out of range exception.

EDIT: Using the ULSViewer when replicating the error does not produce any error messages. When I click on other links it does produce entries in the log, just nothing when I replicate the problem.

EDIT: The stack trace looks like:

> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index]    System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() +78
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) +53
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItemCollection.RemoveAt(Int32 index) +27
>   ASP.adeceef9_c3cf_4497_aaed_b0aa3202002d_489600446.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +67
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +42    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2428

EDIT: OK I have figured out that it is definitely a `View` problem. When I click into a file or folder in the document list, it returns the error from above. However if I remove, from the URL, the text `&View=%7b8439DB47%2d3CED%2d470F%2d9ED5%2d8BA42A63B41C%7d` it displays correctly. So, I don't know how to display this properly automatically. Obviously there is a change I need to make with regards to the Views but I don't know where to start?

Comment: am afraid you might need to provide a bit more of informations for noobs like me ;) lol

Comment: I don't know what other info I can provide to be honest! That's half the reason as to why it is so confusing. There is nothing special about the page/library, it just seems to be random.

Comment: because this is a general error and can occur because of enormous reasons, so I wonder if anyone will be able to answer it without looking at any code or content of your site.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't believe it can possibly be anything to do with code or markup as there is no changes to the code or markup and other document libraries, within the main Sharepoint site, work as expected and they haven't been amended either. While I understand it is a generic error, I believe there must be things I can check without looking into code and markup.

Comment: do it again and upload the log file here.

Comment: Have the forms been customized using SharePoint designer?

Comment: How many items are in the library, are you exceeding any views. What type of site template is being used in this site. Are there any workflows running on any other items in the site? Are there any issues with pages in the page library (if one is being used)?

Comment: @Cory - There are quite a few files in the library. >1500. Would this be a problem? It wasn't a problem on an old site. The site template is the default one, which I then amend the CSS and master page to fit. There are no workflows at all, and no issues with pages in any page library.

Comment: I reduced the file number to around 250 and am still getting the problem.

Comment: Have you tried going back to the defaul style and master page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: "When I try to go into the folders". I mean when **exactly** this error message pops up? At the time you open the library? Or after that, when you actually browse it through its folders?

Comment: Other test would be: save lib as template with contents. And then restore it on another site collection (maybe some site collection for testing). If the problem will be on the testing siteColl, problem is probably in list schema.

Comment: Another thought - check the fields of that library. Any user defined ones? Any feature provisioned ones? I have feeling that this kind of error can be caused by some faulty choice field or something. Maybe use [ListItemEditor](http://splistitemeditor.codeplex.com/) to see and check properties of those docs.

Comment: @jumbo - As I said it seems to be the 2nd level down. I can click down one level, but going to a 2nd level of folders triggers the error. There are no user defined fields. I will try your suggested test but I have created a new list and added the files to that and still having the same problem.

Comment: @anothershrubery, try to modify the web.config to see more details of the error :  http://marcellotonarelli.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/sharepoint-web-config-how-to-show-full-errors/

Comment: I have done all that, the only extra information I can provide is the stack trace, which I have added to the question above.

Comment: Is the URL getting too long? SharePoint has 255 length I believe...

Comment: @anothershrubery Did you happen to find a solution to this problem fine sir?

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds as if it's when you show the default view of the DocLib that it breaks.

Do you know if anything has been changed here?

You might want to open the Site in SharePoint Designer go to the DocLib and add a new view and set it as default. And the try to open the doclib in the browser.

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately, it is still showing the error.

Comment: Can you add any message in the ULS log for the request to the question?

Comment: I've even tried creating a new document library with all default settings and putting the files in there, but still receiving the same error. I don't know where to find the ULS log or what to look for in it...It even happens when I click on a folder which doesn't have any files in it. It seems to be on anything more than a level deep.

Comment: The ULS logs are in the `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS` directory on the Server. The best way to view the is to run [ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3308) while you reproduce the error.

Comment: I have commented in my question above about the ULS log entries but it says: Using the ULSViewer when replicating the error does not produce any error messages. When I click on other links it does produce entries in the log, just nothing when I replicate the problem.

Comment: You probably need to increase the log level to get an error in the ULS logs. You can do this via Central Admin http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to have uls log viewer and then we can help you further.
Install this
http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

Then click on play and it will start streaming the log in realtime.

Then do the action that throws the error.
Then on the logviewer click pause and find the correlation id that the page shows you.

paste the error here

Comment: I have commented in my question above about the ULS log entries but it says: Using the ULSViewer when replicating the error does not produce any error messages. When I click on other links it does produce entries in the log, just nothing when I replicate the problem.

Comment: didnt you see anything as Unexepected in the log? thats pretty uncommon.

Comment: Absolutely nothing was entered into the log when clicking on the link that causes the error. Tried numerous times, but it does not log anything.

Answer (score 0):

Although without having a exact look at the ULS trace , it will be a bit shot in the dark but from what you have explained and the problem that is occuring I think there is a very good chance that we can narrow down the scope of the issue to publishing page layouts and content types.

A number of similar issues with the same "Index Out of range" exception in SharePoint has always occured in the past due to corrupt page layouts and content types used by Document Libraries.

For the above scenario I would rather suggest you closely refer to the below solution:- 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2011/09/06/not-able-to-create-publishing-pages.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if the VIEW FORM has been customized by any chance for this library? You get this exception in the cases where someone inadvertently removed from the View the Original LISTVIEW which ID is used for the proper functioning of any list.
In other words, even if a new view has been added, deleting the original ListView WP can cause this (sometimes even worse, forbid total access to items.
If you do not have any special Metadata (or use custom Content Type) i would suggest you copy all the files (via Windows Explorer View, or use the Manage Content & Structure on Publishing Sites, or simply use Chris O'Brian tool on CodePlex http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/ and re-create the library.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

Can you create another site and move all content from the misbehaving site to the new one (only a copy at first, just get all content from the library using explorer view first, then copy it into the new site). If that works, delete the old site and instruct users to use the new one. If it still doesn't work, check for file name length / weird characters etc. If someone added a file with a bad name (i.e. a # in it) using explorer view it might break sharepoint virtual path provider or something else sharepoint uses to build the menu.