# Index Out of Range when opening folders

Tags: 2007, document-library

When opening a sub-folder in a shared document library to view the files, I receive the following exception:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() +78
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) +53
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItemCollection.RemoveAt(Int32 index) +27
   ASP.adeceef9_c3cf_4497_aaed_b0aa3202002d_489600446.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +67
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Here is where it gets weird. If I right click on the name of the folder and open it in a new IE tab, it opens with no exception! If I click the folder name in the normal fashion to open in the current tab, it crashes out.

Also, if I remove the View parameter from the query string after receiving the error and reload the page, it loads ok.
E.g:
This fails:

```
http://mysite/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fMySite%2fCorporatePolicies%2fCPP%20Documents%2fAudit%20Document%2fEmployeeinfo&FolderCTID=&View=%7b775CF1BC%2dB2DA%2d40BF%2d8365%2d34BD69A18733%7d
```

This works:

```
http://mysite/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fMySite%2fCorporatePolicies%2fCPP%20Documents%2fAudit%20Document%2fEmployeeinfo&FolderCTID=&
```

If I change the view before I try to open the sub-folder, it opens fine regardless of which view I choose. As a result of this, I have tried changing the default views of the library, but it makes no difference.

Comment: did you try to create new view and make that view as default. then test if its still errored out.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Hi, yes I tried that, the same behaviour occurs unfortunately.

Comment: have you checked the solutions in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/index-out-of-range-when-opening-folders-in-shared-documents?rq=1 ?